# Elasticsearch SQL-Query not possible

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-sql

I got a ElasticSearch Instance running locally which works fine. Now I want to query an index using SQL. I tried it with the NodeJS-Client (v7) and normally via the REST-Api.
Rest call:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/_sql
{
   "body": {
       "query": "DESCRIBE indexname"
   }
}
```

And via nodeJS:

```
elasticClient.sql.query({
    format: "json",
    body: {
        query: "DESCRIBE indexname"
    }
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(reject => {
    console.log(reject);
});
```

Both give back the same error:

> Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_sql] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE]  status: 405

Can anyone help? 
Cheers!

Comment: Have the same issue on bonsai... but found nothing yet :-(

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? I suspect you're running the v7 JS client against a v6 cluster

Comment: Can you run the same `POST _sql` request with `curl` or something else other than this client code? (asking because that error message is typical for a setup where either **x-pack is not installed**, or **ES-SQL is not enabled**)
And it helps to know the exact version of ES server. Also, the body of a `POST` request for `_sql` should be `{"query": "DESCRIBE indexname"}`, not sure why you have `body` in there.

Comment: @tiefenb can you elaborate more on the questions asked above? Being interested in a post and, also, offering a bounty for it, but not being ready to help with the investigation is not very productive.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_sql
{
   "body": {
       "query": "DESCRIBE indexname"
   }
}
```

Comment: GET request can't have a body

Comment: and yet it is used that way e.g. in `_search` endpoint

Answer (score 0):

This issue is normally caused by the incompatibility of your elastic/elasticsearch module. What is your ES version? Try to upgrade your NodeJS version to your ES version.

Check the compatibility here.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch